# Failure to re-authenticate Kafka client SASL connection, should close connection

Tags: security, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-security

As per KIP-368 (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-368), when 'connections.max.reauth.ms' is explicitly set to a positive number the server will disconnect any SASL connection that does not re-authenticate.
If the re-authentication attempt fails then the connection will be closed by the broker, retries are not supported.
However when my client fails to re-authenticate, it goes into infinite loops of retry.

```
INFO [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector: [Producer clientId=producer-1][Producer clientId=producer-1] Failed authentication with 10.4.252.249/10.4.252.249 (Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism)
ERROR [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 0 (10.4.252.249/10.4.252.249:9096) failed authentication due to: Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism
INFO [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector: [Producer clientId=producer-1][Producer clientId=producer-1] Failed authentication with 10.4.252.249/10.4.252.249 (Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism)
ERROR [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 0 (10.4.252.249/10.4.252.249:9096) failed authentication due to: Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism
```

I want the client to exit so I can bubble up the exception. 
Any ideas how I can address this?

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Authentication failed: Invalid username or password
```

Kafka will throw SaslAuthenticationException when authenticate fail. You can surround client code with try catch and close the client in the catch block.
Take admin client for example.

```
//... init other properties

// set request time out, the default timeout takes too long
properties.put(AdminClientConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 3000);

// get client
Admin admin = Admin.create(properties);

// test connection, if error happens, close it, in case of infinite retrying to connect to kafka by admin client, because of the meta data update thread
try {
    admin.listTopics().names().get();
} catch (Exception e) {
    closeClient(admin);
    throw new RRException(e);
}
```